# Maven - Is `maven-archetype-simple` a valid archetype?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Usually, I create maven jar project with archetype [`maven-archetype-quickstart`](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/), it works well.

But I want to create Maven project with no sample `App.java` class, thus I tried [`maven-archetype-simple`](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-simple/) archetype, and get error.

**Maven command:**

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=eric -DartifactId=hello -Dversion=0.1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-simple -DinteractiveMode=false -X -DarchetypeCatalog=local`

**Error tip:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate
>   (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The defined artifact is not
>   an archetype -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate
>   (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The defined artifact is not
>   an archetype  at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: The defined
>   artifact is not an archetype  at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:205)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>     ... 20 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationConfigurationFailure:
>   The defined artifact is not an archetype  at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.configureArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:189)
>     ... 22 more [ERROR]  [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the
>   errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

**The questions are:**

- Is `maven-archetype-simple` a valid archetype?
  In the official doc of maven, it says `maven-archetype-simple` is a archetype, refer: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html , but it won't work in my test, so get confused.
- How to create Maven project without the generated code `App.java`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The artifact `maven-archetype-simple` [does exist on Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-simple/), but it isn't a valid archetype since it doesn't containt the right metadata files. A valid archetype [must have in its JAR file](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html):

- either a `META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml` (this is the new format);
- or a `META-INF/maven/archetype.xml` or even a `META-INF/archetype.xml` (this is the old format).

And that specific artifact, as it is present on Central, doesn't have those files. As such, it isn't considered a valid archetype for the plugin. Those files store the required parameters for the archetype, their possible default values, the files that it should use, etc. so they really are required.

I'm not sure there exists an archetype that would generate *just* a lone `pom.xml` with the given Maven coordinates. This is effectively what using the `maven-archetype-quickstart`, without generating the `App.java` and `AppTest.java` would do. Keep in mind that an archetype is really intended at creating a project from a pre-defined template, like a sample Java EE application, or a sample Maven project; all of those would require more set-up than just writing a POM file.

If you really, *really*, do not want those files, you can either

#### [Create your own archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)

Create a new Maven project, for example `my-simple-archetype`, with the following directory structure:

```
pom.xml
src
\---main
    \---resources
        +---archetype-resources
        |       pom.xml
        |
        \---META-INF
            \---maven
                    archetype-metadata.xml
```

Content of `pom.xml` at the root:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eric</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-simple-archetype</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Content of the `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
</project>
```

And finally, content of the `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml`:

```
<archetype>
  <id>my-simple-archetype</id>
</archetype>
```

Now you can build this project and install it:

```
cd my-simple-archetype
mvn clean install
```

This will update your local catalog so that this new archetype is available. You can finally use it! In a new directory, do

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=eric -DartifactId=hello -Dversion=0.1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=my-simple-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=eric -DinteractiveMode=false
```

And you will have as result your wanted project... which consists of the lone `pom.xml`. So, of course, you can now [customize this archetype of yours](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html).

#### Remove the files

Or you decide that it is not worth the effort, and it is a lot simpler to remove the files after their creation:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=eric -DartifactId=hello -Dversion=0.1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
rmdir /S /Q hello\src
```

Or `rm -rf hello/src` if you're on a Linux machine.

Comment: Great to see the example on creating a customized archetype.

Comment: Had the same issue today. Providing an archetype you can't use out of the box sounds really frigging stupid.

Answer (score 1):

About `maven-archetype-simple`, even if it would be valid (which isn't the case), it's a little outdated (2006). I suggest you use something more up to date so that plugins and java versions aren't too old.

`java8-quickstart-archetype` would fit the bill:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=eric -DartifactId=hello \
-Dversion=0.1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=java8-quickstart-archetype \
-DarchetypeGroupId=pl.org.miki -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This archetype sources can be found here: [github.com/mikolak-net/java8-quickstart-archetype](https://github.com/mikolak-net/java8-quickstart-archetype).

Comment: Very useful information, I am going to maintain my own archetype to save time for future projects.

Answer (score -2):

It is a valid maven archetype, see https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=maven-archetype-simple

Comment: Have you tried generating a project with it ? It raises an error and generates nothing. It's been almost 10 years since it was created, perhaps it has to do with maven versions? Anyhow, it doesn't work.

Comment: No it doesn’t - it is broken. It is valid in the sense that OP didn't mistype its name and it is listed on maven-repository.com.

Comment: Listed on Central simply means that it's a regular artifact on which you can depend on. It doesn't make it an archetype because there's `archetype` in the name. For an artifact to be a valid archetype, it must have the right metadata files in it, as I [explained in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40076064/1743880).